# How can I disable Apper?

Tags: 11.10, updates, kubuntu

Since 12.04 came out, "Apper" bothers me every five minutes with a popup "UPDATE NOW!!!!!"

How can I turn this annoyance off?

Comment: By updating?  It's doing that for a reason.

Comment: What is "Apper"? I genuinely do not know. (I already updated when the release candidate was available.) I didn't see any "Apper" pop-ups at the time 11.10 was released.

Comment: @vasa1: I think the process is `/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/apper-sentinel`

Comment: @geekosaur: I will not update right now.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So it's a Kubuntu thing? You could add a _kubuntu_ tag to your question if that's correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**KDE notifications**

System Settings > Application and System Notifications > Event source: Apper Notification.

[image]

**Apper**

The Apper is the KDE interface for PackageKit (aka KPackageKit)

More: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Apper?content=84745

**Kubuntu default**

Kubuntu default package management suite is the Muon.

More: http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/